# error when trying compiling code with variadic parameters

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, variadic

When I try to compile the following code, I receive an C2672 and a C2783 error.
I couldn't figure out how to fix it.

```
class Statement
{
public:
    template<typename T, typename ... Args>
    void Bind_All(Args... args)
    {
        std::vector<T> list = { args... };
    }
}

void func()
{
    Statement stmt;
    stmt.Bind_All(1, 2.5, "3");
}
```

> error C2672: 'Statement::Bind_All': no matching overloaded function found
>
> error C2783: 'void Statement::Bind_All(Args...)': could not deduce template argument for 'T'

Thanks!

Comment: Well, it's saying it cannot deduce `T`, which makes sense as nothing in the arguments depends on `T`. Tell it; that said, what do you think `T` should be here? You are mixing different types in the arguments.

Comment: You also forgot to put semicolon after class declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how this variadic template could be completed and used:

```
class Statement {
public:
    template <typename T>
    static void Bind_All(T value) {}
    template<typename T,typename ... Args>
    static void Bind_All(T value, Args... args)
    {
        Bind_All(args...);
    }
};

void func()
{
    Statement stmt;
    stmt.Bind_All(1,2.5,"3");
}

int main()
{
    func();
    return 0;
}
```

or, if you want to see that different types were actually used:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

class Statement {
public:
    template <typename T>
    static void Bind_All(T value) 
    {
        std::cout << typeid(value).name() << ":";
        std::cout << value << '\n';
    }

    template<typename T,typename ... Args>
    static void Bind_All(T value, Args... args)
    {
        std::cout << typeid(value).name() << ":";
        std::cout << value << '\n';

        Bind_All(args...);
    }
};

void func()
{
    Statement stmt;
    stmt.Bind_All(1,2.5,"3");
}

int main()
{
    func();
    return 0;
}
```

On my system this yields:

```
int:1
double:2.5
char const * __ptr64:3
```

Answer (score 3):

Since `T` is not part of the arguments, there is no way the compiler can deduce `T`. You will need to make it explicit.

```
Statement stmt;
stmt.Bind_All<int>(1, 2.5, "3");
```

However, note that this will not work since '"3"`cannot be converted to an`int` in the line:

```
std::vector<T> list = { args... };
```

You will need to use a list of suitable arguments when calling  `stmt.Bind_All()`.

Comment: Thanks! But what if I want to pass in arguments with various type?

Comment: @XTT, when you want to construct a `std::vector<int>`, you need to pass `int`s or anything that can be converted to an `int` implicitly. You cannot use any old type of object as an argument to construct a `std::vector<int>`.